# Ideal Voltage/Current Sources in the Theoretical Total Resistance of a Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

If someone wants to find the total resistance of a circuit he has to deactivate the independent current sources.

As an ideal independent voltage source has zero resistance and the ideal independent current source has infinite resistance, either working or not, why do we need to deactivate them? Can't we just leave them be and just consider their resistances as zero and infinite respectively?

Simply put do we need to disable them so no current can flow in the circuit (for some reason) or we just do it as a visual aid in order to point out that those element has those resistance "values" in an attempt to simplify the circuit?

My question is purely theoretical and it doesn't have to do with real circuits and resistance measurements with a multimeter.

Comment: What do you mean by deactivate?

Comment: @immibis Deactivating an ideal voltage source is replacing it with a short circuit and an ideal current source with an open curcuit.

Comment: use either Vs or Is  but not both in series

Comment: @Adam Well if you treat it as an infinite resistance how is that different from treating it as an open circuit?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I don't really understand your comment. I am not talking about some specific configuration. There may be a circuit with only a voltage source, one with only a current source or one with multiple of those. Either way when we have to find the total resistance every book says you deactivate them. That is what I don't understand. Why not simply leave them be?

Comment: @immibis It isn't. I never said that I disagree or that it is wrong. Theoretically it is perfectly right. I just don't understand why we have to redraw the circuit and replace those elements. Most books go into detail on to how we deactivate them and that we have to do it as a first step and I don't see why there is all that fuss about it.Why not simply use their resistances without turning them off?

Comment: you can use an Ammeter &' voltage meter to measure with sources active

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 As I mention in my post I am not interested in real cases only in theoretical circuits that you use Circuit Theory.

Comment: In theory everything comes down to common practice.

Comment: Whats the difference of a circuit not being connected and having "infinite resistance" ???

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yes but I am only interesting in the theory and I have a very specific question that has nothing to do with practice.

Comment: in theory nothing

Comment: no  difference of a circuit not being connected and having "infinite resistance"

Comment: oh, got the idea, you mean by "deactivate", to make them stop furnishing current to the circuit... hmm..

Comment: @JorgeAldo Yes. An ideal current source is connected to the circuit and it provides current to it but it has infinite resistance by definition. It doesn't exist that is why it is called ideal.

Comment: if there is one regulated ideal forcing function CV or CC , even =0V or 0A then you cannot inject DMM measurements

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I don't care about real measurements of any kind I have point that out in my question.

Comment: same applies to theory

Comment: Isn't it obvious that there's no theoretical difference between redrawing a circuit diagram without a component, and simply pretending the component isn't there? The only difference is which one is more convenient. If you redraw the diagram then you don't have to remember to pretend the component isn't there.

Comment: @immibis It is not the same thing as when you disabling the sources then you don't have current in your circuit. My main question is whether there is a reason for not wanting active sources or not. Redrawing it the circuit was never an issue it was just mentioned.

Comment: @Adam Do the active current sources affect the calculations in any way?

Comment: @immibis I don't thing so but there could be another reason. That it the point of the question anyway.

Comment: @Adam If it doesn't affect the calculations then changing it has no impact whatsoever on the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about a "linear" circuit.

You don't have to deactivate the internal sources.

You can "measure" (by simulation, if you're talking about a circuit that only exists hypothetically) the output current (remembering that current is taken as positive when it flows *in* to the port) and voltage with any two different loads connected (say two different resistors, or two different voltage sources, or two different current sources). That will give you two points on the I-V curve of the output port. Through these you can draw a line, and the slope of that line is the equivalent resistance of that port.

If you're talking about a nonlinear circuit then you *can not* disable the internal sources. And you must choose two loads that do not disturb the operating point significantly. Then this method will give you the differential resistance near the operating point.

Comment: Can't I just combine the resistances and use zero and infinite resistance for ideal voltage and current sources respectively? I mean to do what you would normally do but with the sources turned on.

Comment: Using zero and infinite resistance for the ideal sources and ignoring their voltage/current values is exactly the same as disabling them.

Comment: I know, as I mentioned in the comments, that it is the same thing...What I want to understand is if disabling has any other benefit or is just a way to visualize the fact that those elements have zero and infinite resistance? I mean do we need to disable them so no current can flow in the circuit (for some reason) or we just do it as a visual aid in order to simplify the circuit?

Comment: Nobody makes you redraw it. You just need to get the slope of the IV curve. However you get it, as long as you get the same number, nobody but you will ever know.

Comment: I mentioned redrawing as an example not that you have to do it! So there is no reason for not wanting current through the circuit? Disabling the sources is just a way of simplification and you can do exactly the same procedure with sources on or off? Do I get it right?

Comment: You want to know \$\frac{\rm{d}V}{\rm{d}I}\$. It doesn't matter how you get it, and the constant voltages and currents generated by the independent sources won't affect it.

Comment: Ok the last part was my main question. No book seems to want to include that part. They just have a list of steps with step 1 disabling the sources. Thank you.

Comment: One benefit of disabling the internal sources is that then you get one "test point" for free: 0 V, 0 A.

Comment: Yes but that is another story!

Answer (score -1):

From a circuit theory point of view any bipole may be modelled as Thevenin or Norton equivalent. In math

\$V=R_\text{Th}I+V_\text{Th}\$ or

\$I=G_\text{No}V+I_\text{No}\$

*note that each above quantity may either be scalar (single port circuit) or vectors of currents and voltages at ports and R or G matrix (multiport circuits)*

\$I_\text{No}\$ and \$V_\text{Th}\$ model internal generators and if disabled (open current generators and short voltage ones) just yields naught reducing the above to

\$V=R_\text{Th}I\$ or \$I=G_\text{No}V\$, easy enough you can now force current or voltage and then measure the counterpart to  get equivalent resistance(conductance) seen at port(s).

\$ R_\text{Th}=\frac{V}{I}\$ or \$ G_\text{No}=\frac{I}{V}\$

Answer (score -1):

The usual method of determining an unknown circuit linear resistance is done by **R=Voc/Isc for open circuit voltage and short circuit current.**

Open circuit is circuit violation of an ideal independent constant current (CC) source or sink, as this would require infinite voltage.

Hence, this is the reason why the CC cannot be ON to measure resistance in a theoretical ideal circuit.

[image]

> [it is not possible to force an independent current source to take up a current which is different from its defined value](http://www.eie.polyu.edu.hk/~cktse/linear_circuits/main/node6.html)

Comment: I dont understand members who downvote correct answers without anything intelligent to comment. Who are you? Either improve the answer  with a comment or ask a question or offer constructive criticism.  otherwise -1 only indicates your incompetence or character.